# ubuntu 16.04 nautilus there is no clickable area in a folder because the folder is full of files

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, nautilus

I cannot click on the folder area when the folder is full of files, and thus I cannot right click to open the context menu and for example "launch terminal".

In other words, no matter where I try to click on with right click, it selects the file or folder, and not the current folder itself.

This might be a minor inconvenience but surely it is not meant to be this way?
There were some older questions where the answer seemed to be to use specific shortcuts but this is complete nonsense, as I want to open the context menu, not to memorize specific keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: The methods described in the link provided by Vanadium also wok in 16.04

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments under the question, the methods described in the context menus link work in version 16.04 as well as 18.04

Simply right click between icons on the folder to obtain the context menu.

[View this short video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmvm2qu81xx03i1/out.ogv?dl=0)

Whilst the directory shown in the video is not exactly full, it contains a significant number of files but the principle remains the same no matter how many files are contained therein.